# No effect from the signals

Tags: django

I want my app users to listen to the action of creating a User instance and exactly after that initialise (create) an Account instance: Unfortunately the following does not work at all:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Account

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_account(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Account.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_account(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.account.save()
```

and my apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

I create a user but it does not dispatch the action for the receivers to created an Account instance. At leas I cannot see them in the Django default administration region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put default_app_config in your app's **init**.py